# node executable could not be found in atom with node-debugger pkg

Tags: node.js, debugging, atom-editor

When I press F5 to start debugging, the below error happens

> Failed to start debugger. Exit code was ENOENT which indicates that the node executable could not be found. Try specifying an explicit path in your atom config file using the node-debugger.nodePath configuration setting.

I tried to add some configuration like below, but it does not work.
I am not sure I added it properly.

vim ~/.atom/config.cson

```
"node-debugger":
    nodePath: "/usr/bin/node"
```

Could you help me? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

There was my mistake writing configuration. I fixed it.

I added like below in  ~/.atom/config.cson.

```
"*":
  editor:
    fontSize: 11
  "exception-reporting":
    userId: "77b3d578-0126-41d7-9cdd-b994407621f0"
  "node-debugger":
    nodePath: "/usr/bin/node"
```

you can refer to the similar issue on the below site.
https://github.com/kiddkai/atom-node-debugger/issues/127

And use the command "which node" to see the node path.