# Node executable could not be found in Atom with node-debugger in mac os

Tags: node.js, atom-editor, node-debugger

When I attempt to run the debugger but I get an error:

> Failed to start debugger. Exit code was ENOENT which indicates that the node executable could not be found. Try specifying an explicit path in your atom config file using the node-debugger.nodePath configuration setting.

Here's my config.cson file:

```
"*":
  core:
    packagesWithKeymapsDisabled: [
      "git-plus"
    ]
  editor:
    fontSize: 16
  "exception-reporting":
    userId: "c1ad4fa3-59a5-4611-baf5-8312a36b059f"
  "node-debugger":
    nodePath: "/usr/bin/node"
    scriptMain: "Users/david/Documents/gitlab/prj/src/app.js"
```

I tried to change the 'nodePath' parameter to '/usr/local/bin/node' but still got the same error.

I checked the following links:
[node executable could not be found in atom with node-debugger pkg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43450193/node-executable-could-not-be-found-in-atom-with-node-debugger-pkg/43463574)

https://github.com/kiddkai/atom-node-debugger/issues/127

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I recently had the same issue, but I was able to fix it by going into the package settings through the UI and changing the `nodePath` to what you mentioned in your post. Just to make sure, did you restart your editor afterwards?

Answer (score 0):

In a terminal window, type `which node`.
Then back in Atom, go to Preferences->Packages->node->Settings.  Enter the path to node in the field `Node Path`.